# Using arrays as custom properties in Blender PropertyGroup

Tags: python, interface

I'm very new to Blender scripting (not programming in general) and I can't seem to figure out how to save an array of some data type (probably want it to be another PropertyGroup) in a PropertyGroup that I put on `bpy.types.Scene.ssData`.

What I have tried so far is variations on this:

```
class SSData(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
  totalCount: bpy.props.IntProperty(name="Subscene Count", description="Integer", default=0)
  list: ['ford']
```

but when I try to get the list property like this: `bpy.context.scene.ssData.list` I get an error `AttributeError: 'SSData' object has no attribute 'list'`. The other property is registered fine btw, I can get `totalCount` and set it to some other value as well.

I've searched in the Blender docs for some Array type that I can use like `bpy.props.IntProperty` but I can't find anything. I understand that the object I want there should inherit from `bpy_structs` but I don't know if I can make my own type based on that.

Comment: Does this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16511/how-can-i-store-and-retrieve-a-custom-list-in-a-blend-file

Comment: @RayMairlot This definitely helps! Thank you very much. I tried something similar as well but I wasn't sure how the CollectionProperty thing works (given it has a function called `add()` that I didn't know about).