# PropertyGroup for Texture Nodes

Tags: python, properties

I would like to create a PropertyGroup Class with some of my own settings and then I would like to assign a settings instance to 4 different Environment Textures in my World.

This is what I would like to achieve for my Textures (example from Blender.org)

```
class MaterialSettings(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    my_int: bpy.props.IntProperty()
    my_float: bpy.props.FloatProperty()
    my_string: bpy.props.StringProperty()


bpy.utils.register_class(MaterialSettings)

bpy.types.Material.my_settings = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MaterialSettings)

# test the new settings work
material = bpy.data.materials[0]

material.my_settings.my_int = 5
material.my_settings.my_float = 3.0
material.my_settings.my_string = "Foo"
```

I defined my class:

```
class Env_Settings(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    env_name: bpy.props.StringProperty()
    env_rot: bpy.props.FloatProperty(default=0)
    env_bright_cyc: bpy.props.FloatProperty(default=1)
    env_bright_eve: bpy.props.FloatProperty(default=1)
```

but I'm having trouble to understand where to hung it under.
I can't put it under:

```
bpy.types.World.env_settings = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=Env_Settings)
```

because then I can only instance it once. (All other instances will get the same values).
So, how can I define 4 instances of my Settings Property for the four Environment Textures in my World node group?
Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: You should use a collection property. I think this should help https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24808/86891 and https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.CollectionProperty.html

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! This is even better as not all of my settings are actually related to the environment texture itself. Initial test works, now I try to implement it in to my Add-On.